# Embedding windows seccurity username and password to aspx page

Tags: asp.net, html, xml

I am trying to put a link for an image of an ip camera in my asp.net application.

Everything is working fine apart from a slight issue.

The issue is that I still get asked for the username and password from windows security everytime

The code is as follows:

```
    </form>
    <p>
        <img align="middle" alt="PC1" src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/jpg/image.jpg" 
            id="reloader" onload="setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'reloader\').src=\'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/jpg/image.jpg?/'+new Date().getMilliseconds()', 500)"
            style="z-index: 1; left: 506px; top: 169px; position: absolute" /></p>
</body>
```

I have tried putting

```
 userid:password@
```

before the IP address but that makes the page an viewable at all.. any help is apreciated

Answer (score 0):

This feature that allowed Internet Explorer to use credentials passed in the URL like this was removed 5+ years ago.  It was seen as a security vulnerability.

Here's the KB article describing the removal of this feature: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489

**Update**

There are a couple of ways to get around this:

1. Turn off authentication on your IP camera.
2. If your .Net server has network access to your IP camera, your .Net app could proxy the request to the camera and take care of the credentials for you.

Comment: ok but is there any other way to over come the issue as i am using asp.net?